# How to convert static IP address to new domain name

Tags: codeigniter

I have developed a website in codeigniter that has been hosted on a static ip address http://182.184.79.154.
Now I want to transfer all the urls of this website to a new domain http://integratedschoolsystem.com.

Can anyone help me how to do this ?

Comment: Google "DNS tutorial", there are 898,000 entries.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you're trying to change the PHP application to address the links, not the DNS entry. In that case, assuming you followed Codeigniter's practices by using `base_url()` for all of your links, then all you have to do is update the config file.

`\application\config\config.php`

Line 26 (usually) is `$config['base_url'] = '';`

So set that to whatever your domain is, in this case:

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://integratedschoolsystem.com';`

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html